# Is there a list of all QSS properties for QSlider in QT for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I've only just started learning to code and i'm using Python 3. I'm making a GUI in PySide2 and have been struggling with customising a slider object. I've managed to bodge some code together to change the shape and size of various components of the QSlider object, but could really use a full list of editable parameters for each objects' stylesheet ideally. The doc.qt.io site either lists every object with a small portion of the changeable parameters and some limited examples, or there is a list of every single parameter on stylesheets from every single object, but doesn't specify if certain properties are exclusive to objects (and some definitely are).

Is there documentation anywhere that lists each object in QT and its associated stylesheet options? The main reason for me making this post is that i was looking for a way to edit a QSlider's handle when it is in a *pressed* state but cannot find what the parameter for that would be. I managed to find that mouseover is done with "*hover*" but not much else.

Comment: I think this is as close as it gets: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: Thanks, i've checked it out beforehand but didn't help much. I've muddled through now though by looking at other code snippets :)